# Symfony 4 make entity regenerate : no changes

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony4

I updated from symfony 4.3 to symfony 4.4 and since (i think), when i regenerate an entity, the new field added is not regenerated.

I add a $new_field in my entity:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * FondsInfos
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="fonds_infos")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class FondsInfos
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $pre_coche_arbitrage;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $new_field;

}
```

After i do :

```
php bin/console make:entity --regenerate App\Entity\FondsInfos
```

Result :

```
updated: src/Entity/FondsInfos.php

  Success!
```

At the end i have all my field except "new_field" generated and i don't understand why!

Somebody has an idea of the problem ? I try lot of things but don't find the problem.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found the problem.

When you update to Symfony 4.4, you need to not forget to update the makerBundle to the last version to be compatible.

Answer (score 1):

I mean the main issue there is that instead of

```
php bin/console make:entity --regenerate App\Entity\FondsInfos
```

use this

```
bin/console make:entity --regenerate App\\Entity\\FondsInfos
```

because you can get console error message as

```
[ERROR] No entities were found in the "AppEntityFondsInfos" namespace.
```

if you don't use \\ in command

*(currently works for Sf 5.3+)*